# Make a comma seperated string from list of objects

Tags: c#, string

I have a list of these objects

```
public class OsloProverModel
{
    public string PersonalNumber { get; set; }
    public string SchoolCode { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to make a *comma seperated file* with the these records. So for example something like this

```
PN1,SC1,E1
PN2,SC2,E2
....
```

I am trying to looping over and concatinating. Is there a way in *Linq* that I can do it?

Comment: Override `ToString` and `string.Join(Environment.NewLine, yourItems)`

Comment: Make sure your source data contains no commas, otherwise you'd be better-off using a CSV serializer that deals with such things correctly.

Comment: Overriding ToString() prevents you from returning a meaningful string for debugging purposes, in a general case. I think better create another method either in the object containing the fields or in the object serializing to csv

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Override `ToString()`

```
public class OsloProverModel
{
    public string PersonalNumber { get; set; }
    public string SchoolCode { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Join(",", new[] { PersonalNumber, SchoolCode, Email });
    }
}
```

so you can

```
OsloProverModel opmItem = new OsloProverModel()
{
    PersonalNumber = "PN1",
    SchoolCode = "SC1",
    Email = "E1"
};
string result = opmItem.ToString(); //"PN1,SC1,E1"
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/7l1G2S

---

or in case of a `List<OsloProverModel>` and a file:

```
List<OsloProverModel> opvItems = GetValues();
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"c:\myfile.csv", opvItems.Select(x => x.ToString()));
```

Answer (score 5):

In *general case* when creating CSV we should add quotations if string contains quotation mark `"`, comma `,` or new line;
let's implement a local function for it:

```
  Func<string, string> quote = (source) =>
    string.IsNullOrEmpty(source) ? 
        "" 
      : (source.Any(c => c == ',' || c == '"' || c < ' ')) ? 
        $"\"{string.Concat(source.Select(c => c == '"' ? "\"\"" : c.ToString()))}\"" 
      : source;
```

Then having a collection of `OsloProverModel` (say, a list)

```
  List<OsloProverModel> data = ...
```

Finally, we can put a simple *Linq*:

```
  File.WriteAllLines(@"c:\MyFile.csv", data
    .Select(item => string.Join(",", 
       quote(item.PersonalNumber), 
       quote(item.SchoolCode),
       quote(item.Email))));
```